# What could cause my NSException to be swallowed up?

Tags: iphone, exception

I have some assertion code that raises an NSException on bad input.

Today, I messed up one of my methods and generated a condition which triggered the exception.  However, unlike usual, XCode didn't stop on the exception raise.  It kept going.  It took me a LOT of NSLog calls to figure this out, because it also unwound the entire call stack so I couldn't figure out where it was dying.

I have a custom unhandled exception function defined (AND breakpointed), and everything was working until today (when I have no idea what changed).

What could cause XCode and/or the Objective-C runtime to swallow my NSExceptions whole and not tell me?

Interestingly, the code kept running just fine - went back out to the main run loop.

==EDIT==

This just happened to me again, 5 days later, in a different place.  Beginning to suspect buggy behavior in Xcode 4 while debugging.  Watch this space.

Comment: Are you expecting it to hit the breakpoint in your unhandled exception function, or do you have an exception breakpoint turned on (or both)?

Comment: @ichinisan - both!  That's what's frustrating.  NSException raise: as well as the unhandled exception handler are both breakpointed, and seem to work in other cases.